# How I can bind textblock with bolded and normal text

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textblock

I have a part of text which some of the words are formatted.
These text are listed in a ListBox. When user clicks ListBoxitem, I want to collect that selectedItem and take user to the other place. My problem is that I cant bind TextBlock with another instance of TextBlock. And that TextBlock has many inlines, which I want to show.

I have been trying this solution:

```
<ListBox Width="800" Name="foundedTextBlocksListBox" SelectionChanged="foundedTextBlocksListBox_SelectionChanged" Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Visible" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="foundedTextBlocks" DataContext="{Binding Textblock}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

After Binding to DataContext like this:

```
            ObservableCollection<FoundedTextBlock> listOfFoundedTextBlockResults = new ObservableCollection<FoundedTextBlock>();
            TextBlock textblock = new TextBlock();
            while (blockString.IndexOf("<b>") != -1)
            {
                int startOfWord = blockString.IndexOf("<b>");
                int endOfWord = blockString.IndexOf("</b>");
                string text = blockString.Substring(0, startOfWord);
                textblock.Inlines.Add(text);
                string boldedWord = blockString.Substring(startOfWord + 3, endOfWord - startOfWord - 3);
                textblock.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = boldedWord, FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold });
                blockString = blockString.Substring(endOfWord + 4);
                textblock.Inlines.Add(blockString);
            }
            textblock.Tag = dbInfo;
            listOfFoundedTextBlockResults.Add(new FoundedTextBlock() { Textblock = textblock });
        }
        foundedTextBlocksListBox.DataContext = listOfFoundedTextBlockResults;
```

I can't see any ListBoxItems in ListBox. Is my Binding wrong or is this possible at all?
I managed before to get TextBlock.Text property to show but not the Inlines where are bolded text or any other Inlines after my first inline addition to TextBlock.
How I can solve this annoiyng problem? In short, I need to display many TextBlocks with formatted text...

FoundedTextBlock class has TextBlock textblock {get;set;} property
I'm saving to Tag property my class instance, so I could collect the information I need when SelectedValueChanged event occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use a ContentPresenter instead of TextBlock in your XAML

Replace

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="foundedTextBlocks" DataContext="{Binding Textblock}"></TextBlock>
```

with

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Textblock}" />
```

Please try it out ... the rest of your code is missing to provide a better answer.

Comment: I cant believe my eyes, this worked!!! I was sure that this is not possible or something, because I've been googling answer for this already for days. Thank you so much. You saved my day SIR!

Comment: No Problem :) But maybe you should think about to implement two value converter http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx one for the FontWeight and one for removing the Html Tags